# Spinnaker conflicting with Qt when included

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt5, spinnaker-cam

Everything works fine before I include *Spinnaker.h* into my code. It seems like there is some conflicting issues between *Spinnaker* and *Qt5*.

This is what I get when I include *Spinnaker*.

> In file included from /opt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork/QtNetwork:32:0,
>
> from /opt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/gcc_64/include/QtQml/QtQmlDepends:4,
>
> from /opt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/gcc_64/include/QtQml/QtQml:3,
>
> from /opt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/gcc_64/include/QtQuick/QtQuickDepends:5,
>
> from /opt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/gcc_64/include/QtQuick/QtQuick:3,
>   from /home/torch/projects/slam_multi_threaded_ws/src/leo_slam  /torch-gui/mainwindow.cpp:5:
>
> /opt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork/qnetworksession.h:96:32: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
>
> ```
> QNetworkInterface interface() const;
>                             ^
> ```
>
> /opt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork/qnetworksession.h:96:33: 
>    error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
>
> ```
> QNetworkInterface interface() const;
> ```

Do you have any idea how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Spinview seems to install it's own version of Qt.  The path you are using is not the Ubuntu Qt, which would be in '/usr/include'.  For Ubuntu 18.04, I nuked the spinnaker Qt and just used the stock Qt libraries.  I haven't re-encounter the issue with Ubuntu 20.04, so Flir may have wised up and used the Qt that comes with Ubuntu.  Alternatively, adjust your include paths... unless your question is about using the spinnaker deployed Qt?  But most  people wouldn't want this.